# Exclude default fields from python `dataclass` `__repr__`

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, repr

**Summary**

I have a `dataclass` with **10+ fields**. `print()`ing them buries interesting context in a wall of defaults - let's make them friendlier by not needlessly repeating those.

**Dataclasses in Python**

Python's [`@dataclasses.dataclass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) ([PEP 557](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/)) provides automatic printable representations ([`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)).

Assume this example, [based on python.org's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#:%7E:text=from%20dataclasses%20import%20dataclass):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class InventoryItem:
    name: str
    unit_price: float = 1.00
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0
```

The decorator, through [`@dataclass(repr=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=__repr__#:%7E:text=parameter%20is%20ignored.-,repr,-%3A%20If%20true%20(the) (default) will [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) a nice output:

```py
InventoryItem(name='Apple', unit_price='1.00', quantity_on_hand=0)
```

**What I want: Skip printing the defaults**

`repr` It prints *all* the fields, including implied defaults you wouldn't want to show.

```py
print(InventoryItem("Apple"))

# Outputs: InventoryItem(name='Apple', unit_price='1.00', quantity_on_hand=0)
# I want: InventoryItem(name='Apple')
```

```py
print(InventoryItem("Apple", unit_price="1.05"))

# Outputs: InventoryItem(name='Apple', unit_price='1.05', quantity_on_hand=0)
# I want: InventoryItem(name='Apple', unit_price='1.05')
```

```py
print(InventoryItem("Apple", quantity_on_hand=3))

# Outputs: InventoryItem(name='Apple', unit_price=1.00, quantity_on_hand=3)
# I want: InventoryItem(name='Apple', quantity_on_hand=3)
```

```py
print(InventoryItem("Apple", unit_price='2.10', quantity_on_hand=3))

# Output is fine (everything's custom):
# InventoryItem(name='Apple', unit_price=2.10, quantity_on_hand=3)
```

**Discussion**

Internally, here's the machinery of `dataclass` `repr`-generator as of python `3.10.4`: [`cls.__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.4/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1043-L1045)`=`[`_repr_fn(flds, globals))`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.4/Lib/dataclasses.py#L588-L596) -> [`_recursive_repr(fn)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.4/Lib/dataclasses.py#L391-L409)

It may be the case that `@dataclass(repr=False)` be switched off and `def __repr__(self):` be added.

If so, what would that look like? We don't want to include the optional defaults.

**Context**

To repeat, in practice, my `dataclass` has **10+ fields**.

I'm `print()`ing instances via running the code and repl, and [`@pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html) when running [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/) with `-vvv`.

Big dataclass' non-defaults (sometimes the inputs) are impossible to see as they're buried in the default fields and worse, each one is disproportionately and distractingly huge: obscuring other valuable stuff bring printed.

**Related questions**

As of today there aren't many `dataclass` questions yet (this may change):

- [Extend dataclass' __repr__ programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67327282/extend-dataclass-repr-programmatically): This is trying to *limit* the repr. It should show *less* fields unless they're explicitly overridden.
- [Python dataclass generate hash and exclude unsafe fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740748/python-dataclass-generate-hash-and-exclude-unsafe-fields): This is for hashing and not related to defaults.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```py
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass
from operator import attrgetter


@dataclass(repr=False)
class InventoryItem:
    name: str
    unit_price: float = 1.00
    quantity_on_hand: int = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        nodef_f_vals = (
            (f.name, attrgetter(f.name)(self))
            for f in dataclasses.fields(self)
            if attrgetter(f.name)(self) != f.default
        )

        nodef_f_repr = ", ".join(f"{name}={value}" for name, value in nodef_f_vals)
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({nodef_f_repr})"
        

# Prints: InventoryItem(name=Apple)
print(InventoryItem("Apple"))

# Prints: InventoryItem(name=Apple,unit_price=1.05)
print(InventoryItem("Apple", unit_price="1.05"))

# Prints: InventoryItem(name=Apple,unit_price=2.10,quantity_on_hand=3)
print(InventoryItem("Apple", unit_price='2.10', quantity_on_hand=3))
```

Comment: Nice! I wonder if `repr=False` is really necessary (and can't test myself right now) – wouldn't defining `__repr__` override the built-in method anyway?

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary as you said. However, I left it there as a "reminder" that we actually replaced  `__repr__`

Comment: @user2246849 This works! Thank you. Are you willing to additionally license the code in your answer under MIT or [Python license](https://docs.python.org/3/license.html#bsd0)? I'd like to use it (I can still give attribution and link to your answer as well)

Comment: @TonyN yes of course, feel free to use it as you wish. I added a license snippet to my profile.

Comment: @user2246849 Thanks for your reply and clarification! That's a fair point, especially if the  `def __repr__` is buried somewhere deep down in a more complex class.

Comment: Here is your answer in action: Definition [`libvcs.utils.dataclasses.SkipDefaultFieldsMixin`](https://github.com/vcs-python/libvcs/blob/v0.13.0a3/libvcs/utils/dataclasses.py#L5) and [usage](https://github.com/vcs-python/libvcs/blob/v0.13.0a3/libvcs/utils/subprocess.py#L71) + [docs](https://libvcs.git-pull.com/internals/dataclasses.html). I added doctests. When using it as a subclass I need to pass `repr=False` to `@dataclasses.dataclass`. When using `__repr__` directly it can be omitted.